# Lock a ToggleButton after checking

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a GUI which is built with the MVVM-Pattern. In the View there is a Toggle-Button, which `IsChecked` property is bound to a bool property in the ViewModel.

Now it is only allowed to turn the ToggleButton (and the bool property in the ViewModel) from false to true over the View. A method resets the bool property in the ViewModel, so the user can switch the Toggle-Button again from false to true.

How can I lock the Toggle-Button in the View, without using the `IsEnabled` Property?

Thanks.

Comment: Why **without** using the `IsEnabled` property? Wouldn't that be the easiest way to do it? That way the user also sees that he can't uncheck it by hand and wont get frustrated trying it.

Comment: Toggle buttons should be able to be toggled when enabled. Not allowing users to do that is going to frustrate them. Either disable it, or use a different control. Or a different pattern, as this is an uncommon and unexpected UI pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with using IsEnabled? Your users will quickly get frustrated if they click on what appears to be a regular toggle button and nothing happens.

If you realy want to go down this path, you could write something like this as the binding source for the button's IsChecked property.

```
    private bool _isToggleButtonChecked;

    public bool IsToggleButtonChecked
    {
        get { return _isToggleButtonChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (_isToggleButtonChecked)
                return;

            _isToggleButtonChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsToggleButtonChecked");
        }
    }

    private void ResetIsToggleButtonChecked()
    {
        _isToggleButtonChecked = false;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsToggleButtonChecked");
    }
```

Comment: Now the ToggleButton can change, but the VM will get out of sync with the view

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you don't want to use the `IsEnabled` property, but just for the heck of it, here is an extension property that could easily be done in one line of code-behind (but that wouldn't be very MVVM and would be less fun):

**Disclaimer**
This works exactly as you described but there are a lot easier ways to do this. If you want to avoid using `IsEnabled` because of the grayed out look, simply re-style the button any nobody will notice the difference.

```
public static class ToggleButtonExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanNotUncheckByHandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CanNotUncheckByHand", typeof(bool), typeof(ToggleButtonExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnCanNotUncheckByHandPropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void OnCanNotUncheckByHandPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (!(dependencyObject is ToggleButton)) return;

        if ((bool)eventArgs.NewValue)
            ((ToggleButton)dependencyObject).Click += OnClick;
        else
            ((ToggleButton)dependencyObject).Click -= OnClick;
    }

    public static void SetCanNotUncheckByHand(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(CanNotUncheckByHandProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        ((ToggleButton) sender).IsChecked = true;
    }

    public static bool GetCanNotUncheckByHand(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(CanNotUncheckByHandProperty);
    }
}
```

```xaml
<ToggleButton local:ToggleButtonExtensions.CanNotUncheckByHand="True"/>
```

Basically what this does is making sure that the ToggleButton stays Checked whenever it is unchecked by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Although I highly advise using the `IsEnabled` property, binding the toggle state to a the visibility of a transparent canvas using an `IValueConverter` should work for you.

```
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton Content="Hello"/>
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" Visibility="Visible"/>
</Grid>
```

[Here's a link to the MSDN page for the BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That would only partially work - ToggleButtons can also be toggled with the keyboard (e.g. Space). This would only prevent the user from clicking it and an easier way to achieve that would be to set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false`.

Comment: They can be toggled with the keyboard, but you are unable to put focus on the toggle-button if the canvas is blocking interaction with it, therefore you are unable to use the keyboard to toggle it anyway, from what I've experienced.

Obviously it is not an airtight solution, but given the circumstance I believe it's sufficient.

Comment: Focus can be set with `Tab`, also the Focus will still be set after the first click.

Comment: You are entirely correct, let's just hope the OPs users don't press tab. The canvas will prevent all and any mouse interaction however.